# Is there a way to create a private lobby?

Tags: mordhau

I'd like to host a private lobby so a few friends and I can chop each other's heads off. Is there a way to do so in Mordhau?

I may be blind, but I didn't see anything in the main menus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways.

The easier option is to rent a server. Go to the server browser and select rent server. This will cost a bit, but it's easy to setup and reliable.

The other option is to host your own dedicated server. This will require quite a bit of setup work, but if you did something like this before, like in the good old Quake 3 engine games time, you shouldn't have any trouble.

[Here is a guide for Windows](https://mordhau.com/forum/topic/10250/how-i-got-my-dedicated-server-ot-run-and-appear-on/) and [here is one for Linux](https://mordhau.com/forum/topic/10348/dedicated-server-hosting-guide-linux/?page=1)

The support tools for your own dedicated server aren't really there yet, so it'S possible, it'll get easier over the next months.